# Error while compiling android / phonegap application on android studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I get the following error when I try to run my android phonegap app on android studio.

Android Dex: [AppName] Unable to execute DX

What do I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me before is the below.

- Close the IDE.
- Delete bin folder inside your project folder.
- Start IDE and clean your project.
- Now run and give a try.

Also check if you have included any libraries multiple times.

Did you tried to build via CLI tools of Cordova/PhoenGap?

Comment: Removing my application's bin & the bin folder within CordovaLib fixed this for me.